# WindowBuilder on Eclipse 4.7 - Installation error

Tags: eclipse, windowbuilder

Whenever I add this repository:
`http://download.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/WB/integration/4.7/`

and try to install `WindowBuilder`, the following error appears after 48%:

> An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
>       session context was:(profile=epp.package.java, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=,
>   action=).
>       Unable to read repository at http://download.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/WB/integration/4.7/plugins/org.eclipse.wb.rcp.databinding.emf_1.9.1.201710100405.jar.
>       Read timed out

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be solved by manually downloading the file in the link to the plugins folder and installing WindowBuilder components one by one, make sure to install SWT components at last.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Eclipse for RCP and RAP Developers, Version: Indigo Service Release 2
I faced this same issue while downloading the WindowBuilder.

I tried installing it directly from "Install new Software", provide the below repository link:

```
indigo - https://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo/
```

If you are using any other version of Eclipse like 2021-09, use the below one:

```
2021-09 - https://download.eclipse.org/releases/2021-09
```

You can refer to all the Eclipse repositories from here:  **https://download.eclipse.org/releases** and choose the one that suits you. Hopefully, it will solve this issue.